# SQL server count another rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: i have database like this...]

[image: how i can result like this ?]

how i can result like this ?
in my mind i can query = >

```
select id, count(no1, no2, no3) where no1='B',no2='B',no3='B'
```

thank's very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Case When` statements with `Count` aggregate. Lastly, Group them with `id`:

```
Select id, 
       count(case when  no1='B' then 1 END) +
       count(case when  no2='B' then 1 END) +
       count(case when  no3='B' then 1 END) AS count_all
From yourtable
Group by id
```

Comment: Both `Count` and `Group by` is not needed it is a unnecessary overhead

Answer (score 3):

Use `Case Statement`

```
select id, 
       case when  no1='B' then 1 else 0 END +
       case when  no2='B' then 1 else 0 END +
       case when  no3='B' then 1 else 0 END As Count_All
From yourtable
```